# Turn off simultaneous touches in SKScene / Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, multi-touch, skscene

I am currently developing a game where the user should only be able to touch with one finger at a time. I am using `SKScene` and have tried searching for ways to disable the multi-touch functionality, but nothing turned up. I was thinking of just manually calling "return" on all touches between `touchesBegan()` and `touchesEnded()` were called, but that method is flawed too ([SpriteKit SKScene missing touchesEnded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689885/spritekit-skscene-missing-touchesended?rq=1)).

So my question is: How can I only allow one touch at a time in SKScene?

Answer (score 7):

SKView inherits from UIView, so, in didMoveToView add:

```
self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ironically enough, after days of finding nothing I came up with a hack right after posting this question. Notice though, that it is a hack, and it is not optimal, so I am still looking for better suggestions. The hack is as follows:

Inside touchesBegan(), replace:

```
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        // Whatever is being done on touch
    }
```

with:

```
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        if(CACurrentMediaTime()-lastTouchDate < 0.1) {
            return;
        }
        lastTouchDate = CACurrentMediaTime();
        // Whatever is being done on touch
    }
```

This way, only the first touch will be registered, when multiple touches are coming in at once, or right after each other. if(CACurrentMediaTime()-lastTouchDate < 0.1) checks if it is less than 0.1 seconds since the last touch was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

thats worked for me

```
self.view?.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
```